# An error with opening Multi-Series Line Chart from Mike Bosktok

Tags: d3.js, referenceerror

I'm practicing d3 with Mike Bostok's example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955

I'd like to see how the series that he made - cities - looks like.

I opened the html file using Python local server and in the console, I wrote 'console.log(cities);' but it didn't work. 'console.log(data);' also didn't work. They all showed this error message:

```
VM100:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: cities is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:13
```

I didn't make any modification in his code. So I don't think there is an error in the code. I assume perhaps the problem is in line with d3 setting?
So, I've tried to open the file in Firefox and I've also downloaded d3 but those two ways also didn't work.

Does anyone happen to know what is the cause of the problem? 
If someone can explain how the 'cities' in his code looks like, then you are the most welcome!

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, the reason `cities` is `undefined` is because your `console.log` statement is somewhere outside of the callback function provided to `d3.tsv`. If you look closely at Mike's code, you'll notice that the third argument to `d3.tsv` is a function that receives as an argument an error object and the processed data. Inside that function, he defines the `cities` variable, so if you put `console.log(cities)` anywhere outside of that function, `cities` will be `undefined`.

Now, on to the format of the data. If you look further down that block, there's another file: data.tsv. It has four columns: date, New York, San Francisco, Austin. `d3.tsv` will create an array where each element in the array corresponds to one row in the TSV (except for the header row). Each row is converted to a plain JavaScript Object with properties that correspond to the columns of the file. That array is passed into the callback as the `data` variable in this block. So `data[0]` will be

```
{
  "date": "20111001",
  "New York": "63.4",
  "San Francisco": "62.7",
  "Austin": "72.2"
}
```

When the `cities` variable is defined, that array is transformed into an array that contains one item per city, and each object representing the city contains the time-series data of temperature for that city. So the `cities` variable will look like:

```
[
  {
    "id": "New York",
    "values": [
      {"date": Date 2011-10-01T00:00:00, "temperature": 63.4},
      {"date": Date 2011-10-02T00:00:00, "temperature": 48.0},
      ...
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "San Francisco",
    "values": [...]
  },
  {
    "id": "Austin",
    "values": [...]
  }
]
```

It's probably worth pointing here the second argument to `d3.tsv` in this example: the `type` function. This is where all the strings are converted into `Date` or `Number` objects. Without this argument, all of the property values in `data` would be strings.

For more information on how `d3.tsv` works, you can check the docs for [d3-request](https://github.com/d3/d3-request#tsv).

**CAVEAT**: that block is for d3v4, the latest version of d3 is v5. In v5, d3-request is deprecated in favor of [d3-fetch](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch). d3-fetch provides pretty much the same set of utilities for fetching data, but instead of using callback functions, they return [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

Comment: Hi @darth_mall, thank you for your reply. I was wondering if the data structure that you showed isn't how 'data' is parsed through d3.tsv? I was confused if the variable 'cities' is defined in a different way? in particular, to destingish the three cities/colours?

Comment: @Sue, right, sorry I was careless in my response. The format of the data I showed is the structure of the `data` argument that is passed into the callback for `d3.tsv`. The line where Mike Bostock assigns a value to `cities`, he is reformatting the data. I'll update my answer with those details.